# Sending keystroke to a process

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I want to write a seperate program that can receive commands from network and replay these commands to `omxplayer`. `omxplayer` is the video player on raspberry pi, we can control `omxplayer` via the keystroke. May anyone please suggest some approaches that we can send keystroke event to a running process?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use FIFO to send keystrokes to omxplayer.

We'll show you a basic example of how you do it.

In Shell (Terminal 1),

```
mkfifo /path/to/dir/fifo
omxplayer /path/to/movie/dir/movie.ext < /path/to/dir/fifo
```

after you execute these commands, the terminal 1 will hold.

Now in terminal 2

```
echo -n . > /path/to/dir/fifo
```

now it will start play.

This was the basic example. You can create a php file to write to the fifo file. So from that you can send commands.

> p will pause
>
> q will quit

also, when using non-letter commands (like up arrow, and down arrow), you should send the correct key code.

Hope this helps.